# Convert "array-of-objects" to "object-of-objects" in TypeScript with full typing and generics

Tags: typescript, algorithm, generics

I have this pure JavaScript algorithm what taking `array of objects` and convert it into `object of objects`. Main purpose is to convert lists from REST APi array format into format what is better for Read/Update/Delete operations.

Algorithm look like this:

```
export const reduceRecursively = data => {
  return data.reduce((acc, val) => {
    acc[val.id] = val;
    for (let key in acc[val.id]) {
      if (val.hasOwnProperty(key) && Array.isArray(val[key])) {
        val[key] = reduceRecursively(val[key]);
      }
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
};
```

Example:

```
// Input
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'test',
    wheels: [
      { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
      { id: 2, name: 'bar' }
    ],
  },
];

// Output
{
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'test',
    wheels: {
      1: { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
      2: { id: 1, name: 'bar' },
    },
  },
};
```

I need to convert this into fully typed (strict mode) TypeScript equivalent with usage of generics, because this is helper function for many different models.

**There is one pre-condition: Every object have `id` property. This will be true always.**

I tried different ways but I was not able to do it in strict mode.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic function to capture the actual type of the array item passed in. You can then use a custom mapped type to get the desired output type:

```
interface ObjectWithId {
    id: number;
    [name: string]: string | number | boolean | ObjectWithId | Array<ObjectWithId>
}

type Id<T> = {} & { [P in keyof T]: T[P] } // Can be removed. Just used for nice tooltips

type ReduceRecursively<T extends ObjectWithId> = Record<string, Id<Omit<{
    [P in keyof T]:
    T[P] extends Array<infer I> ? I extends ObjectWithId ? ReduceRecursively<I> : I[] : T[P]

}, 'id'>>>


export const reduceRecursively = <T extends ObjectWithId>(data: T[]) => {
    return data.reduce((acc, val) => {
        acc[val.id] = val;
        for (let key in acc[val.id]) {
            if (val.hasOwnProperty(key) && Array.isArray(val[key])) {
                // The unsafe part
                val[key as keyof T] = reduceRecursively(val[key as keyof T] as any) as any;
            }
        }
        return acc;
    }, {} as Record<string, any>) as ReduceRecursively<T>;
};

let r = reduceRecursively([
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'test',
        wheels: [
            { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
            { id: 2, name: 'bar' }
        ],
    },
]);
// Inferred as: 
// Record<string, {
//     name: string;
//     wheels: Record<string, {
//         name: string;
//     }>;
// }>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=45&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#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-AoIJAf4AHPCybIcg+3JxP4WZBFmdCFjeRq3uyuokQak7CAu1Y5swbAAIxAvujBiBIbASpAMgSrxEFCK2q4GlIbCsRJNaUEwrDIDx7DiJIyASlMBgSjU4mgQwSmccgABMIICZpEroLuelQTWigGUhdCVlmy4kCAxLOBMzZsHQy7oZhqiAsh-kNEIlkqAC8hueFjBSRAMlsIFfzBcCVBhQekXIFhgKxZB5GZUEgS0HQUDCFxih9AlMnCAADFVllAA)

This should mostly work, there may be corer cases I missed but it should get you started.